# Get item of recursive observablecollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, recursion, observablecollection

I have a TreeITem class with a observablecollection.

```
/// <summary>
/// Item class to generate a tree view of the queues and topics from the service bus.
/// </summary>
public class TreeItem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The whole namespace tree
    /// </summary>
    public static ObservableCollection<TreeItem> Tree { get; set; }

    //TreeItem properties
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> Items { get; set; }
    .........
```

If I create a tree structure I do the following:

```
            //Get queues and topics
            TreeItem namespaceTree = new TreeItem() { Name = namespaceManager.Address.ToString() };
            TreeItem queuesTree = GetQueues(namespaceManager.GetQueues());

            //Get queues and topics
            TreeItem namespaceTree = new TreeItem() { Name = namespaceManager.Address.ToString() };
            TreeItem queuesTree = GetQueues(namespaceManager.GetQueues());
            TreeItem topicsTree = GetTopics(namespaceManager.GetTopics());         

            //Generate the topic structure.
            namespaceTree.Items.Add(queuesTree);
            namespaceTree.Items.Add(topicsTree);
            Tree.Add(namespaceTree);
```

If I bind the tree to the tree view everthing works fine but when I want to get a element from the Tree I have a problem. For instance I tried to get a special topic from the Tree it didn't work. I tried it with the following code:

```
    private TreeItem GetTopicFromTree(ObservableCollection<TreeItem> tree)
    {
        TreeItem treeItem = null;
        foreach(var item in tree)
        {
            if (!item.Name.Equals("topicx"))
                GetTopicFromTree(item.Items);

            else
                treeItem = item;
        }

        return treeItem;
    }
```

But with the recursion it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
private TreeItem GetTopicFromTree(ObservableCollection<TreeItem> tree)
{
    foreach(var item in tree.Items)
    {
        var found = GetTopicFromTree(item);

        if (found != null)
            return found;
    }

    return null;
}
```

But TreeItem is not an `ObservableCollection`, so you'd need a 2nd method of `GetTopicFromTree` to handle `TreeItem`.

```
private TreeItem GetTopicFromTree(TreeItem tree)
{
    if (Name.Equals("topicx"))
        return this;

    foreach(var item in tree.Items)
    {
        var found = GetTopicFromTree(item);

        if (found != null)
            return found;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Or, perhaps a touch cleaner

```
private TreeItem FindTopic(TreeItem node, string name)
{
    if (node.Name == name)
        return node;

    foreach (var child in node.Items)
    {
        var found = FindTopic(child, name);
        if (found != null)
            return found;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hy, thank you very much for your help everything worked fine.

Best regards and have a nice day

Comment: @user2644964 good to hear. if this was the solution you needed, feel free to mark it as the answer (check mark on the left side). I like the points :)